# Checkboxes not working PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I have a problem in the WP-Pro-Quiz plugin for WordPress. There are "Single Answer Options" that are visible, but not selectable. I need these options, I was thinking I might be able to get the checkboxes to function and in turn get the result I need in my quiz.

What is causing these checkboxes to be "Greyed Out"?

```
       <?php
}
private function singleChoiceOptions($data)
 {
    $single = $data[0];
    ?>
    <div class="postbox" id="singleChoiceOptions">
        <h3 class="hndle"><?php _e('Single choice options', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?></h3>

        <div class="inside">
            <p class="description">
                <?php _e('If "Different points for each answer" is activated, you can activate a special mode.<br> This changes the calculation of the points',
                    'wp-pro-quiz'); ?>
            </p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answerPointsDiffModusActivated"
                       value="1" <?php $this->checked($this->question->isAnswerPointsDiffModusActivated()); ?>>
                <?php _e('Different points - modus 2 activate', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?>
            </label>
            <br><br>

            <p class="description">
                <?php _e('Disables the distinction between correct and incorrect.', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?><br>
            </p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="disableCorrect" 
                       value="1" <?php $this->checked($this->question->isDisableCorrect()); ?>>
                <?php _e('Disable correct and incorrect.', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?>
            </label>

            <div style="padding-top: 20px;">
                <a href="#" id="clickPointDia"><?php _e('Explanation of points calculation', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?></a>
                <?php $this->answerPointDia(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: Remove it `<?php $this->checked($this->question->isDisableCorrect()); ?>`, along with `disabled="enabled"`. I think it's returning the `disabled` attribute again. But **make sure you know what you're doing**, IDK if it'll corrupt your plugin's functionality.

Comment: So remove all of the code you have in your comment? `<label> <input type="checkbox" name="disableCorrect" value="1" <?php $this->checked($this->question->isDisableCorrect()); ?>>  <?php _e('Disable correct and incorrect.', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?> </label>`

This is what I currently have in there.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect where it is at currently. `disabled="enabled"` has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The are gray because the are disabled by `disabled="enabled"`, even if the value is `enabled`, the input gets disabled, any value will disable the input, in fact, you can just put `disable` and it will be disabled, latest browers just read `disabled` and disable the input. remove `disabled="enabled"` and the input will be enabled.

Comment: TL;DR: The `disabled` attribute is a boolean.

Comment: @rnevius boolean? I'm not [so sure](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html)

Comment: I just did that, and still nothing.

Comment: @taxicala I removed that bit of code, but when I go to view it live by inspect element it shows disabled="disabled" even though I do not have that code in there any longer.

Comment: there must be something else adding that attribute then.

Comment: @AlanMachado , you're in agreement then. If the `disabled` attribute is present, the input will be disabled. [It's a boolean attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled). Even the spec [defines it as such](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#attr-fe-disabled).

Comment: Boole stated it clearly, there is TRUE or FALSE, and not TRUE, FALSE and HALF-FALSE. The mozdev and w3c docs states boolean for the reduced attribute, which isn't compliant with XHTML standards (and neither is what OP's trying to use).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the name values weren't matching the $this value, capital letters. Plugin author must've missed it. Hopefully the function works.

```
        <div class="inside">
            <p class="description">
                <?php _e('If "Different points for each answer" is activated, you can activate a special mode.<br> This changes the calculation of the points',
                    'wp-pro-quiz'); ?>
            </p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="AnswerPointsDiffModusActivated" value="1" <?php $this->checked($this->question->isAnswerPointsDiffModusActivated()); ?>> 
                <?php _e('Different points - modus 2 activate', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?>
            </label>
            <br><br>

            <p class="description">
                <?php _e('Disables the distinction between correct and incorrect.', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?><br>
            </p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="DisableCorrect" 
                value="1" <?php $this->checked($this->question->isDisableCorrect()); ?>>
                <?php _e('Do not show correct and incorrect.', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?>
            </label>

            <div style="padding-top: 20px;">
                <a href="#" id="clickPointDia"><?php _e('Explanation of points calculation', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?></a>
                <?php $this->answerPointDia(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
```